# How to fix this Python BMI calculator?

Tags: python, debugging

This is a BMI calculator that I wrote in python

```
print('BMI calculator V1')

name = str(input("What's your name?"))
weight = int(input("Your weight in Kilograms"))
height = float(input("Your height in Metres"))

def function(w, h):    #function here is the bmi calculator
     bmi = w / h ** 2
     return("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))

bmi_user = function(weight, height)  
print(bmi_user)  

if bmi_user < 18:
     print(name + "," + "you are underweight")
elif bmi_user > 25:
     print(name + "," + "you are overweight")
else:
     print(name + "," + "you are normal")
```

It shows the following error when I run the code

> line 15, in 
>       if float(bmi_user) < 18:
>  ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: You can't do comparisons between a string and a double.

Look at what your function returns: a string.

```
def function(w, h):    #function here is the bmi calculator
     bmi = w / h ** 2
     return("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))

bmi_user = function(weight, height)
```

You'll do better with this:

```
def bmi_calculator(w, h):    
     return w / h ** 2
```

Comment: Thanks, This was for a project.

Answer (score 1):

Fix it by not returning a string from your calculation. You should give this [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a read and follow it to debug your code.

```
print('BMI calculator V1')

name = str(input("What's your name?"))
weight = int(input("Your weight in Kilograms"))
height = float(input("Your height in Metres"))

def calcBmi(w, h):    # function here is the bmi calculator
     bmi = w / h ** 2
     return bmi        # return a float, not a string

bmi_user = calcBmi(weight, height)  # now a float
print(f'Your BMI is: {bmi_user:.2f}')   # your output message

if bmi_user < 18:
     print(name + "," + "you are underweight")
elif bmi_user > 25:
     print(name + "," + "you are overweight")
else:
     print(name + "," + "you are normal")
```

`function` is not a really good name, I changed it to `calcBmi`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function def function(w, h):  returns a string as below.

```
return("Your BMI is " + str(bmi))
```

This cannot be compared with an integer as specified in your statements like below.

```
if bmi_user < 18:
```

The below line also will be an error

```
elif bmi_user > 25:
```

Change your function as below, it will work

```
def function(w, h):    #function here is the bmi calculator
    bmi = w / h ** 2
    return bmi
```